# Why can't I add a WCF DataSetvice to an ASP.NET C# Process in MVS Express 2013 for Web

Tags: c#, wcf, odata, wcf-data-services, visual-studio-2013

I've been trying to follow tutorials for exposing an OData service
that wraps an SqlServer Entity model in C#.
Setting up the entity model works fine, but, although I've used nuget to install everything concievably relevant, and although it says that it succeeded, when I try 
add new item WCF Data Services
I don't get the right thing listed as a possiblility (as seen in e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg601462.aspx)  I do see WCF Service (Ajax enabled), but that isn't the right thing.

Is this some deliberate limitation for C# in MVS Express 2013 for Web? Am I holding it wrong.
[I'm a Java developer, so this foray into Visual Studio and C# is somewhat uncharted ground for me. It seems pretty good. If it worked as described.]